# Replacing spaces between html tags with nbsps

Tags: javascript

I want to replace spaces between html tags with nbsps using pure JavaScript. 
This is my html:

```
<div><span>Apple</span>     <span>Grapes</span></div>
```

You can see spaces between 2 span nodes. These spaces should be replaced by &nbsps.

Result should be:

```
   <div><span>Apple</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span>Grapes</span></div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: CSS: `div {white-space: pre-wrap;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple logic

```js
var input=  "<div><span>Apple</span>     <span>Grapes</span></div>"

var output = input.replace( /<\/span>\s*<span>/g, function(match){ return match.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;") } );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Note that if you need to preserve exact visual whitespace and the input is `...<span>\n <span>` the output should be visually *one* space wide because a single linefeed immediately following a tag is considered line wrapping and the linefeed is not counted as whitespace as per HMTL parsing rules.